# How do I keep track of the numbers inputted in a while loop

Tags: python, loops

My task was to write a program with a loop that iterates (i.e., repeats) exactly seven times.  On each iteration, (i.e., repetition) it should ask the user to enter an integer, and keep a running sum of all integers entered.

When the loop is finished, it should display the total, the average (float with 1 decimal place), and the largest of the 7 numbers...

Here's my code so far...

```
value = 0
totalNumbers = 0
allNumbers = 0

while value < 7:
  secretNumbers = int(input())
  totalNumbers = totalNumbers + secretNumbers
  
  value = value + 1

print("Total =", totalNumbers)
print("Average =", totalNumbers / 7)
print("Largest =", allNumbers)
```

I am aware that this code won't do the job right now. How do I keep track of all the numbers the user has inputted so I can find the largest one?

*Note: Right now allNumbers is not used*

Comment: A list will help you.

Comment: If you only want the largest, then keep track of the largest, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to keep track of all the numbers! In your function statement, you can read the first number before the loop. 
Then, in your while loop, you can check if the current number is bigger than the current largest number(allNumbers).
In this case, you would set allNumbers to whatever the current number is.

**Full Code:**

```js
value = 0
totalNumbers = 0
allNumbers = int(input())
totalNumbers = totalNumbers + secretNumbers

while value < 6: # Only 6 times, not seven, because we read the first value already
  secretNumbers = int(input())
  totalNumbers = totalNumbers + secretNumbers
  
  value = value + 1
  if secretNumbers > allNumbers:
    allNumbers = secretNumbers

print("Total =", totalNumbers)
print("Average =", totalNumbers / 7)
print("Largest =", allNumbers)
```

Comment: To make the code a bit simpler, you can just read the first number before the loop and execute the loop 6 times. You'll avoid this None checking :)